# Problems with Java and Servlet Mapping

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I've mapped my servlet in this way in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HomeServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

And I'm trying to call this:

```
<a href="/HomeServlet" class="brand"><img alt="logo" src="img/Logo2.png"></a>
```

But when I click on the link I get this error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HomeServlet

type Status report

message /HomeServlet

description The requested resource (/HomeServlet) is not available.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You are calling the root of your webserver - you need `/appName/HomeServlet`.

Comment: Exactly, the `/` specifies the root of your web-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the name of your context before `/HomeServlet`. If you're using JSP, you can solve this using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/HomeServlet" class="brand"><img alt="logo" src="img/Logo2.png"></a>
```